# How to not discard 0's at the beginning of a number that is parsed via Integer.parseInt

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, integer

So I basically have a database that is stored externally on the server which I am connected to using the JDBC driver. I have a GUI where you can basically traverse through each record in the database, add/delete/modify data. I have a list of customer records and they have a passport number. The problem is if these numbers start with 0's, when I search for the passport number to see the record on the table it won't show. However when I search a customer who has the passport number such as 891029380 then this will show. When I am creating a customer and specify their passport number through the GUI then the full passport number will be stored on the database and it will record passport numbers that begin with 0's. Is there possibly any way of overriding the Integer.parseInt method where when specifying in a JTextField the passport number to search for a particular customer. It will show the customer's details relating to that number (a number beginning with 0's) rather than not.

Comment: If it's a text string, why are you parsing it as int? Just read it as a String. Maybe if you show us some code, we can help you more.

Comment: The reason is because I want to search through multiple ways, the problem is if I make it a string then I will get a NumberFormatException error since the searching and editing of customer details solely depends on the value of that one textfield.

Comment: if the values in the DB start with zeros, I'm going to assume your column is some type of varchar, or similar. This is how the data should be represented in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. If 0's in front of the text matter, then that's not a number (since with 001 = 1 if treating numbers) and there's no way to make Integer.parseInt() parse it with a different semantic. Show us some code (where you parse and then use the field content).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should treat passports as Strings, especially since you aren't performing operations on them. To ensure the text field contains a number, you can use a regular expression:

```
String text = textField.getText();
boolean isANumber = text.matches("[0-9]*");
```

Comment: He should likely implement that regex in one of these:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html